# Split a string column based on a logic into two new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` :-

| Type |
| --- |
| 9F,5F/6F,3T,1T |
| 18F/19F,2F,9T,4T |
| 17F/12F |
| 3T |
| 3T,2F/3F |
| No Types |

I want to generate these two additional columns based on `Type` column ,All wordsending with Fs seperated in one and all Ts seperated in another column respectively.If `Type` is `No Types` then `No Types` in both the columns:-

| Type | Fcol | Tcol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9F,5F/6F,3T,1T | 9F,5F/6F | 3T,1T |
| 18F/19F,2F,9T,4T | 18F/19F,2F | 9T,4T |
| 17F/12F | 17F/12F | Absent |
| 3T | Absent | 3T |
| 3T,2F/3F | 2F/3F | 3T |
| No Types | No Types | No Types |

Comment: What's your question? What do you need help with exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask]. If you need somewhere to get started, consider `.apply()`, the `.str` accessor, and/or regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and a regex:

```
# extract F and T parts
df2 = df['Type'].str.extract('(.*\dF)?,?(\d+T.*)?')

df[['Fcol', 'Tcol']] = df2.fillna('Absent')

# identify no F nor T
m = df2.isna().all(axis=1)
# and fill original values for those
df.loc[m, ['Fcol', 'Tcol']] = df.loc[m, 'Type']
```

Output:

```
               Type        Fcol      Tcol
0    9F,5F/6F,3T,1T    9F,5F/6F     3T,1T
1  18F/19F,2F,9T,4T  18F/19F,2F     9T,4T
2           17F/12F     17F/12F    Absent
3                3T      Absent        3T
4          No Types    No Types  No Types
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qhe6D7/1)

Comment: `# and fill original values for those
df.loc[m, ['Fcol', 'Tcol']] = df.loc[m, 'Type']` what is `m` here?

Comment: @Scope this is a boolean mask for rows with no matches

Comment: `df2 = df['Type'].str.extract('(.*\dF)?,?(\d+T.*)?')` is this same line we can add for `fillna()` condition Absent?

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot that ;)

Comment: could you recheck the solution , uts working for some and mot for many..especially if type starts witha  T eg `5T,2F`

Comment: I thought you said the values were always in this order

Comment: In my example i had taken a few that way but can be in any order comma seperated